# Vue.js: Toggle CSS class for dynamical data with method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toggle

I have the following code:

```
<template>
<div id="projects">
  <Header />
  <b-container>
    <div class="row">
      <div :class="colSize" v-for="(data, index) in projects" :key="data._id">
        <b-card :title="data.name" :sub-title="user.jobresponsibilities">
          <p class="card-text">
            {{data.description}}
          </p>
          <b-btn v-b-toggle="'collapse'+index" @click="showCollapse(data)">Toggle Collapse</b-btn>
          <b-collapse :id="'collapse'+index">
            <b-card>
              description
            </b-card>
          </b-collapse>
        </b-card>
      </div>

    </div>
  </b-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/Header'
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  components: {
    Header
  },
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    showCollapse(data) {
      this.colSize = 'col-8'
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: this.$store.getters.getUser,
      projects: this.$store.getters.getProject,
      colSize: 'col-4',
      show: false
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#projects {
    background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}
</style>
```

Store.js: https://jsbin.com/kejinihoci/edit?js

[image]

What I want to achieve is that when I click on the toggle button, that the column size of the specific is changed (css class) and that it only show the collapsible for this item and not the other.

I tried to add an ID to the v-model to add it to my method but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something dynamic like assigning an unique id (`id="'collapse'+index"`) to each `collapse` and use `v-b-toggle` directive inside the correspondent button `v-b-toggle="'collapse'+index"` :

```
   <b-btn v-b-toggle="'collapse'+index" class="m-1">Toggle Collapse</b-btn>
      <b-collapse id="'collapse'+index" >
        <b-card>
          description
        </b-card>
      </b-collapse>
```

to make the class changes dynamically you should add a property called `descShown` to your `projects` array.

in `getProject` action inside your `store`

```
        let project = resp.data.project
        project=project.map((p)=>{
               p.descShown=false;
               return p;
               })
        commit('getProject_success', {
          project
        })
```

inside template:

```
    <div :class="['col-8':data.descShown,'col-6':!data.descShown}" v-for="(data, index) in projects" :key="data._id">

   ...
  <b-btn v-b-toggle="'collapse'+index" @click="showCollapse(index)">
```

your method should be like :

```
   showCollapse(index) {
        this.$set(this.projects,index,true);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This sounds reasonable and works. But how can I change the CSS class of the div when I toggled?

Comment: you could keep `@click="showCollapse(data)"` and that would change the class name inside the method

Comment: Thats what I tried but ```showCollapse(data) { this.colSize = 'col-8'}``` changes every card and not only the one I toggled :>

Comment: could you show the store code, i will try to find a way to make class dynamic based on projects array

Comment: Sure! Thats my store.js: https://jsbin.com/kejinihoci/edit?js
so in {{project}} I have a project.name, project.employees, project.start and project.end that I get from the API back.

Comment: i added details i hope that could help you

Answer (score 1):

This is a good opportunity to utilize what vue is built for - components!
Create a new component for your `<b-card>`, pass the props you need down to it. Each of these components will have its own set of data and methods.

```
  <div :class="colSize" v-for="(data, index) in projects" :key="data._id">
    <b-card 
        :cardinfo="{
           data.name,
           user.jobresponsibilities
        }"
    ></b-card>
  </div>
```

```
Vue.component('b-card', {
  props: {
    cardinfo: {
        type: Object
    }
  }
}
```